# Logo in Responsive Design Won't resize to fit Mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, header

I have a problem that I believe is a quick solution... I simply can't figure it out myself, however, and a quick run through search didn't help me either.

Basically, the only real issue I'm having I'd like to address is the logo (SERVICE FIRST) not shrinking down to fit inside of the width of the site in a mobile form. While the rest of the site responds fairly nicely (as nice as it usually gets) to the responsive web design, the header image doesn't so much as twitch, meaning it runs "off" the edge of the page.

My site is at www.test.servicefirstsvc.com

If you view it on a mobile device, or simply shrink your web broswer window to a phone size, you'll see the problem. Any help? I can paste relevant portions of the responsive CSS if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give the `img` tag a `max-width: 100%;` via CSS.

You should add a `height: auto;` as well because of some weird issues with the Safari browser not paying attention to the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... unfortunately, no bueno. Here is my CSS.art-logo-919440050
{  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: 0px !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
      z-index: 101;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%; !important;
}

Comment: And here is the HTML -> <a href="http://www.servicefirstsvc.com" target="_self" title="Service First" class="art-logo art-logo-919440050">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo-919440050.png" alt="" />

Comment: You need to apply that CSS directly to the <img> tag, not the wrapping <a>. So just give it an extra CSS class and move the max-width code there.